# Are there file write functions in Python that have the same safety as ACID does in databases?

Tags: python, acid

I was wondering if there are any functions for writing to files that are like what the ACID properties are for databases. Reason is, I would like to make sure that the file writes I am doing won't mess up and corrupt the file if the power goes out.

Comment: What kind of file is it? Could you use an SQLite database serialized to disk?

Comment: Please elaborate. What kind of files are you writing and how do you exactly want python script to work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Atomic state storage in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220803/atomic-state-storage-in-python)

Comment: I'm working with mainly text files. I would use databases if I could, but what I'm working on is a team project, and no one else wants me to switch to databases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you're doing with your files and the platform there are a couple options:

- If you're serializing a blob from memory to disk repeatedly to maintain state (example: dhcp leases file),
  if you're on a Posix system you can write your data to a temporary file and 'rename' the temporary file to your target. On Posix compliant systems this is guaranteed to be an atomic operation, shouldn't even matter if the filesystem is journaled or not. If you're on a Windows system, there's a native function named [MoveFileTransacted](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/archive/2005/12/28/507866.aspx) that you might be able to utilize via bindings. But the key concept here is, the temporary file protects your data, if the system reboots the worst case is that your file contains the last good refresh of data. This option requires that you write the entire file out every time you want a change to be recorded. In the case of dhcp.leases file this isn't a big performance hit, larger files might prove to be more cumbersome.
- If you're reading and writing bits of data constantly, sqlite3 is the way to go -- it supports atomic commits for groups of queries and has it's own internal journal. One thing to watch out for here is that atomic commits will be slower due to the overhead of locking the database, waiting for the data to flush, etc.

A couple other things to consider -- if your filesystem is mounted async, writes will appear to be complete because the write() returns, but it might not be flushed to disk yet. Rename protects you in this case, sqlite3 does as well.

If your filesystem is mounted async, it might be possible to write data and move it before the data is written. So if you're on a unix system it might be safest to mount sync. That's on the level of '**people might die if this fails**' paranoia though. But if it's an embedded system and it dies **'I might lose my job if this fails**' is also a good rationalization for the extra protection.

Answer (score 1):

The [ZODB](http://www.zodb.org/) is an ACID compliant database storage written in (mostly) python, so in a sense the answer is yes. But I can imagine this is a bit overkill :)

Either the OS has to provide this for you, or you'll need to implement your own ACID compliancy. For example, by defining 'records' in the file you write and, when opening/reading, verifying which records have been written (which may mean you need to throw away some non-fully written data). ZODB, for example, implements this by ending a record by writing the size of the record itself; if you can read this size and it matches, you know the record has been fully written.

And, of course, you always need to *append* records and not rewrite the entire file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that your main goal is to ensure the integrity of written files in case of power failures and system crashes. There a couple of things to be considered when doing this:

- Ensure that your data is written to disk when you close a file. Even if you close it, some of the data may be in OS cache for several seconds waiting to be written to the disk. You can force writing to disk with `f.flush()`, followed with `os.fsync(f.fileno())`.
- Don't modify existing data before you are certain that the updated data is safely on the disk. This part can be quite tricky (and OS/filesystem dependent).
- Use file format that helps you to verify the integrity of data (e.g. use checksums).

Another alternative is to use sqlite3.

Regarding my second point, I highly recommend this presentation: http://www.flamingspork.com/talks/2007/06/eat_my_data.odp. This also covers issues with "atomic rename".