# Python: Atomic Operations

Tags: python, transactions, atomic

In a scenario where there is a set of functions that run in order as one atomic operation. If any of them failed for some reason, the operation must rollback.

Are there any tools for Python to implement this?

Example:

```
create a folder >> move some files >> send an email >> append data to a log file > etc.
```

Comment: "rename a file >> move the file" : https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html. "append data to a log file" : built-in file IO

Comment: The best way to handle things like this is *don't modify the original*. Rather, do everything with a copy, and then once you're sure it all works, delete the original. In this case, is there a particular reason you can't do `rename a file` and `move the file` in the same step (thus causing nothing to happen if the operation fails)?

Comment: hmm I just suggest `os` as I saw you asked for module. for network folder, you may play a bit with `request`. "could be using files in different locations", I don't get this much, could you explain a bit ?

Comment: @AbdulrahmanBres "my question is about atomicity principle", are you looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352106/any-write-functions-in-python-that-have-the-same-safety-as-acid-does-in-database) ?

Comment: @AbdulrahmanBres Did you come up with anything yet ? I have similar use case. I have to Update a field in a database, then transfer file, then remove that file from its original location as an atomic transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Context Manager can be super useful when you have a series of steps that need to work together smoothly or be undone entirely if something fails.

Here is example code:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

# Create the context manager
@contextmanager
def atomic_operation():
    try:
        create_folder()
        move_files()
        send_email()
        append_to_log()
        yield  # Operation successful, commit
    except Exception as e:
        rollback_folder_creation()
        rollback_file_movement()
        rollback_email_sending()
        rollback_log_appending()
        raise e

# Using the context manager
with atomic_operation():
    print("All tasks completed successfully")
```

When an exception occurs within the `try` block, the program in the example above handles it by executing the `except` block that matches the exception type. It then proceeds to run the rollback functions for each task, in order to correctly undo the previously completed tasks. If an exception happens after a specific task, only the rollback functions for tasks completed before that point will be called.

For instance, if an exception occurs after `create_folder()`, only `rollback_folder_creation()` will be called. If an exception occurs after `move_files()`, both `rollback_folder_creation()` and `rollback_file_movement()` will be called, and so on. Therefore, it runs the appropriate rollback functions based on where the exception occurred, rather than executing all four rollback functions.

The rollback operation of some operations may be very easy to do:

```
def rollback_folder_creation():
    folder_path = "/path/to/created/folder"
    if os.path.exists(folder_path):
        os.rmdir(folder_path)  # Remove the folder
        print("Folder creation rolled back")

def rollback_file_movement():
    source_path = "/path/to/original/file"
    destination_path = "/path/to/moved/file"
    if os.path.exists(destination_path):
        shutil.move(destination_path, source_path)  # Move the file back
        print("File movement rolled back")
```

But it may be more troublesome fore mail. There may be two ways to handle email rollbacks:

If the operation of sending an email fails, a rollback operation will be triggered automatically, and a rollback email will be sent to notify the receiver.

You can create an email draft and send the email only after the entire atomic operation has successfully completed.

```
try:
    create_folder()
    move_files()
    email_draft.create_draft()
    append_to_log()
    email_draft.send_email()
```

Comment: You wrote: "if an exception occurs after create_folder(), only rollback_folder_creation() will be called" - but if any of the functions in the `try` block raises an exception, *all* functions in the `except` block are called. The way this works relies on all `rollback_*` functions checking if their respective action has been done at all (as you have shown for `rollback_create_folder` and `rollback_move_files`).